# Swipe down scroll view to dismiss view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I use a `ImageScrollView` from [here](https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView), which is basically a `UIScrollView` to allow pinch to zoom into a picture. I now wanted to add the possibility to swipe down the picture to dismiss the view controller. I created a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and it works fine if zoom scale is at the minimum value (so the whole picture is visible without zoom). But how can I skip the pan gesture recognizer if the zoom scale is above the minimum value? Because it lays on top of the `ImageScrollView`, I can't scroll in the picture because scrolling gesture is fetched by the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Share your code for Swipe action and Zoom value parameter

Answer (score 0):

It's too easy to handle this operation by adding a trigger on swipe action (gesture calling method).

When `zoomScale > minimumValue`; set `return`statement

A simple example with Swift 4:

```
let zoomScale: 1.0
let minimumValue: 0.5

func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

   if (#<set pan gesture down moving condition>#) {
      if (zoomScale > minumumValue) {
        return
      }
   }

// perform your next operations

}
```

Comment: Share your code for Pan gesture and zoomScale operation. So I can provide you exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

For show image like whatsApp imageView functionality you go with the apple framework [QuikLook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook). It will automatically handle Zoom, Dismiss the image while Swipe etc.

It also support for the documents. It will reduce your effort a lot